# Does the option to validate a deploy without saving for metadata that aren't in the Metadata API format exist in sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, mdapi, source

Is it possible to deploy metadata with sfdx to orgs that don't have source tracking, such as sandoboxes, either with `sfdx force:source:deploy` or `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`?
The first one uses metadata in source format, the second one uses Metadata API. With the second one it is possible to validate the deploy without saving to the org using the `--checkonly` option. Is There a similar option for the source format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **force:source:deploy** command does not have this flag . Note that the force:source:deploy was in BETA and salesforce plans to heavily change this in future and may also deprecate  . You can see the proposed change specs [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1) .

Since **mdapi** commands is what that will persist in the future I would go with it .

Update:

From summer 19 looks like force:source:deploy and force:source:retrieve commands will be fully supported with same feature set as mdapi command.